# Not Parsing XML Data Correctly with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

**SOLVED** - Thanks for your help everyone!

Before I get to my code, I'd like to offer a short explanation of what it is I'm trying to accomplish. I have an XML file in the Data folder, which has 3 Elements per descendant: Month, High and Low. Each descendant is already in the appropriate order based on Month, but I need to convert the high and low strings to doubles, so that I can use them to plot points on a graph. That is the part I am unable to accomplish.

What I have so far:

```
    double month = 25;
    const double temp = 275;

    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Data\\";
    XDocument xmlSource;

    private void btnShowAlbany_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Brush, Polyline, PointCollection for drawing
            SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
            Polyline myLine = new Polyline();
            myLine.Stroke = myBrush;
            myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
            PointCollection myPoints = new PointCollection();

            double theTemp = 0;

            //Get XML data
            xmlSource = XDocument.Load(path + @"\Albany.xml");
            var myTemps = from tmp in xmlSource.Descendants("temp")
                            select new
                            {
                                Month = tmp.Element("Month").Value,
                                High = tmp.Element("High").Value,
                                Low = tmp.Element("Low").Value
                            };

            //Pull out data for points
            foreach (var x in myTemps)
            {
                double high = Convert.ToDouble(x.High);
                double low = Convert.ToDouble(x.Low);
                theTemp = (high + low) / 2;

                myPoints.Add(new Point(month, temp - theTemp));
                month += 25;
            }

            //Add points to line, add line as child of canvas
            myLine.Points = myPoints;
            albanyCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing data source", "Show Temps", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

(Note: My canvas grid values begin at 25 X, 275 Y, eg. a temp of 25 in Feb would be plotted @ 50,250)

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Temps>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Jan</Month>
    <High>31</High>
    <Low>15</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Feb</Month>
    <High>35</High>
    <Low>17</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Mar</Month>
    <High>44</High>
    <Low>26</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Apr</Month>
    <High>58</High>
    <Low>37</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>May</Month>
    <High>69</High>
    <Low>47</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Jun</Month>
    <High>78</High>
    <Low>57</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Jul</Month>
    <High>82</High>
    <Low>62</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Aug</Month>
    <High>80</High>
    <Low>60</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Sep</Month>
    <High>72</High>
    <Low>52</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Oct</Month>
    <High>60</High>
    <Low>40</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Nov</Month>
    <High>48</High>
    <Low>32</Low>
  </Temp>
  <Temp>
    <Month>Dec</Month>
    <High>36</High>
    <Low>21</Low>
  </Temp>
</Temps>
```

Comment: [Extract Method](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) is your friend. It's good practice to separate UI code from business logic, too.

Comment: Show us your XML. It might be important.

Comment: What is not working in your current code? Are you getting an exception, or just not getting the output data you expected?

Comment: I'm not getting the output data I'm expecting. I've tried a bunch of different things, but it seems like I'm not getting any output or anything from the foreach loop.

Comment: `Temp` should be spelled with uppercase `T`

Comment: The lowercase T was the problem! I can't believe I overlooked the! capital letter. >_<

Comment: @liho1eye: Add that as an answer :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham way ahead of ya :)

Comment: For future problems involving Linq, you can set a breakpoint and check `myTemps.ToList()` to be able to manually inspect the list.  In this case, you would have found it was empty, or you wouldn't have hit the break point (in which case you would know there was an exception thrown somewhere in the method before that breakpoint), or you would have had an exception thrown when accessing `ToList()` (in which case you would known that your query was invalid somehow).

Comment: I would also recommend the LINQPad for debugging this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding debugging this junk in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is case sensitive. Fix your selector to be `.Descendants("Temp")`

Answer (score 4):

Is `from tmp in xmlSource.Descendants("temp")` correct?

Your XML nodes are called `Temp`, and XML is case sensitive

Your `double high = Convert.ToDouble(x.High);` looks okay so long at the data in the XML is valid, for safety you might try something like

```
double high;
if (!double.TryParse(x.High, out high)) {
    // handle error
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out, try to break your code up in smaller methods, it will be more readable and more maintainable that way

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely work on my code organization and readability in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
Convert.ToDouble(string)
```

Comment: I believe double.Parse(string) is more commonly used.  Convert.ToDouble calls double.Parse anyway.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways.

You can do Convert.ToDbouble(string) as suggested above but an exception would be thrown if it can't parse out the number.

You can try

```
double d;
Double.TryParse(strToParse, out d);
```